# How reliable are Broadcast Receivers across different brand phones?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I have manifest declared Broadcasts for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` and `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`. I tested my app after I removed it from Recent apps screen. I tested it on two phones:

1. MOTO G4 Play(Nougat)- After I removed my app from Recent apps screen on this phone I was receiving broadcasts.
2. ASUS(Lollipop)- After I removed my app from Recent apps screen on this phone I was not receiving broadcasts.

One way after reading such questions on SO I got is that I can do it by starting a sticky service so what it will do is not terminate my process and I will continue to get broadcasts.

What should I do to ensure that I receive broadcasts on every phone without using a service ?

Edit-1:I register my broadcasts as follows in Manifest

```
 `
        <receiver android:name=".PhonecallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"
                    android:enabled="true"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
                    android:enabled="true"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    `

     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("onReceive ","Called"); //This is how I check whether broadcast was called or not
            //... other code
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation? It is hard to help without seeing the code.

Comment: @PedroMassango Done.

Comment: It's because some manufacturers have force close on swiping apps away and some don't. When app is force closed broadcasts will no longer be heard until user opens app again manually.

Comment: @SteveM Then how do apps like truecaller work on the same phone ? I am closing truecaller on the same ASUS phone but when phone call is incoming its dialogbox shows up ? If it would have been force closed from swiping apps no code would have ran.

Answer (score 1):

Think of notification broad cast that can be used to generate notification for your app, so broadcast is pretty reliable.

You are using manifest declared broad cast so theoretically, you should be able to receive broadcast regardless of whether your app is in foreground or background ( similar behavior was expected in all phone since your app targets same API). But there has been cases where mobile devices has ignored/bug some of the contract as a result some expected behavior  breaks. It is very likely that similar thing happened in your ASUS based test.
From the broadcast manager documentation ,

> If you declare a broadcast receiver in your manifest, the system
>   launches your app (if the app is not already running) when the
>   broadcast is sent.

However there is exception .Android has some updates on this behavior recently to restrict some of this features.

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

So what I believe is you should be receiving all broadcasts as long as you target API level less than 26 regardless of your app being active or not. Moving forward to API 26 or greater, you will receive broadcast regardless only if it is explicit OR exempted broadcast as per above quote.

What you encountered is probably that device specific issue which was not supposed to happen. Try testing in few more devices to rule this out.

You may want to read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) for more clarification.

p.s. try not using error logging for  info/debug like `Log.e("onReceive ","Called");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still Is using a service only way to keep the application process alive on devices like the ASUS one ? Also both the broadcast actions I am using are exempted so I don't think there will be any issue for my app going forward.

Comment: That is the only way I am aware of .